# pre-cache node_modules in Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, continuous-integration, npm-install

It frustrates me that CI builds for projects which use Node tool chains such as Grunt and Gulp take quite a long time, the bulk of which is consumed by `npm install`.

I've tried to set up a Docker image, pre-baked with all of the node_module dependencies in the npm cache (each at the same fixed release as declared in my package.json file), but even then the build still takes a few minutes when all it really should need to do is to copy a few directories from the npm cache into my project's node_modules.

I've set `cache-min` to 9999999, but it still seems to take much longer than it shoul need to.

I've looked [local-npm](https://github.com/nolanlawson/local-npm) and [npm_lazy](https://github.com/mixu/npm_lazy) but they seem over the top, and the former takes ages to install - I suspect that it's trying to download every single npm module in existence - I only need a limited number and don't need to be running a web server to serve them from within the Docker container.

...am I missing something?  There must be a faster way to run a CI build...

Comment: did you check how much time it takes to download based image containing npm modules?

Comment: @atv no, that's not the problem. The image download is actually pretty fast, but even with fixed versions, npm still wants to download and build everything, rather than just copying the directories from cache

Comment: @NicholasAlbion could you please share your Dockerfile? I'm trying to do something similar now

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by using .npmrc to point to the npm cache within the docker container.  I would suggest you to docker exec into your container and run `npm config list | grep cache` to ensure that the cache is used.

Comment: Can you post please more details, about exactly steps how to do it?